# do we need new amazon key pairs if we switch aws instances?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services

I switched amanzon aws instances but have tried to reuse the pem file which I was using previously - is a new key pair required if we switch instances on amazon aws?
I am trying to troubleshoot why I cannot log onto the ubuntu instance (I have tried ubuntu/ec2-user/root/bitnami @ the address but with no luck).  The ssh ports are open on the new port according to the aws console.

Any help in troubleshooting this will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you have the same key file associated with your new instance. You should be able to do this through the AWS management console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home).

Comment: thanks for answering - the keypair is associated with the instance.  Anything else I can do to troubleshoot the ssh issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who responded.  I should have spent more time troubleshooting on my end.  The issue was 'ME' -  I had to remove the RSA key from my ssh known hosts section on my computer (it had strict checking).
Once I removed the key, I was able to ssh to the AWS instance.

Once again, thanks for the feedback everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change or alter a key pair on a running instance. Whichever key-pair the instance is started with or the volume was created with, is the one you need to login with. Suggestion to terminate the instance and re-start it or create a instance tied to that older volume and try to login then.

Comment: Thank you for answering - that's what I thuoght.  I have tried restarting the instance & even terminating/starting a new one (with the same keypair).  In the aws console, the instance is showing that its using the same keypair. I have tried ubuntu/root/bitnami/ec2-user ID's - the SSH ports are also open.  Yet, I am still unable to successfully ssh to the new instance.  Is ther anything else I can do to troubleshoot what's causing the issue?  Once again, thanks for reverting.

Comment: Is it in the same security group as the previous instance, too?

Comment: Hi Daan - yes it is.  The issue was with my SSH setup as noted above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your specific problem is. There's no need to create a new key when a new server is started. However, I had a key stop working on me before. It was working for a few months on maybe 15 servers. Then suddenly it stopped working one day. I had to add a new key and from then on I used the new key to create instances. Not sure what happened nobody at amazon seems to be able to explain it to me.

**edit**

You can still log into the old machines with your old key. Just any new machines will have to be created with the new key.